# Send blob data to NodeJS server from Angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Hopefully I'm asking a clear enough question here;

What I'm trying to do is capture user media from a users camera (whether it be a webcam, or phone), and then post that information to a NodeJS server where it will be manipulated / uploaded / parsed, etc.

At the moment I have a button that will capture a scene from the camera and draw it to a canvas, and then sending it to the Node server for further processing.

I'm at the point of pulling my hair out. I've attempted to send the POST information as base64, which didn't work, and then tried converting it to a blob and posting it that way, to no avail.

The end result always leaves me with and empty request body.

I've been searching SO relentlessly yet have not been able to find anything that I've been able to hack to make work with my application.

Using Angular2 with Node v8.9.3

My upload.component.html:

```
<video #cameraCapture width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<canvas #cameraCanvas width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<form (ngSubmit)="uploadTest()">
    <button type="submit">Save Test</button>
</form>
```

In my upload.component.ts:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      let cameraCap = this.cameraCapture.nativeElement;
      if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
              .then(stream => {
                  cameraCap.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                  cameraCap.play();
              });
      }
  }

  uploadPicture() {
      let cameraCan = this.cameraCanvas.nativeElement;
      let cameraCap = this.cameraCapture.nativeElement;
      cameraCan.getContext('2d').drawImage(cameraCap, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      let blob = this.b64toFile(cameraCan.toDataURL());
      console.log(blob);
      let conf = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined}};
      this.http.post('/api/image', blob).subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log(res);
          }
      );
  }

b64toFile(dataURI): File {
    // convert the data URL to a byte string
    const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // pull out the mime type from the data URL
    const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    // Convert to byte array
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // Create a blob that looks like a file.
    const blob = new Blob([ab], { 'type': mimeString });
    blob['lastModifiedDate'] = (new Date()).toISOString();
    blob['name'] = 'file';

    // Figure out what extension the file should have
    switch(blob.type) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            blob['name'] += '.jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            blob['name'] += '.png';
            break;
    }
    // cast to a File
    return <File>blob;
}
```

In my server.js, I have a simple API request:

```
app.post('/api/image', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple at this point, but my head is becoming rather flustered.

Thanks for any suggestions / ideas.

Comment: When you `console.log(blob)`  right before you send the POST, is there data? I.e. the problem exists with the request itself?

Comment: Yes, when I do the pre-post console.log I can see the data, it's only post-post that I cannot see anything, (I.E once it hits Node). I've tried supplying various headers, the latest was defining it as 'Content-Type': undefined, I can see the request to /api/image being made however what's logged is just { }. I've tried changing bodyParser to: app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

and using extended: false, same result.

Comment: @Jesse, is this resolved? I am having the same issue. Please post the solution here